# Passing Variable from Batch to vbs file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

simply i want to use a batch file to read from text file and then pass the string to vbscript
the vbs will display the text information.

i am able to read but unable to display

here is the batch code

```
Option Explicit 
Dim InputFile 
Dim FSO, oFile 
Dim strData 
InputFile = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\output.txt" 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile) 
strData = oFile.ReadAll 

SET AvayaContent1=strData
START c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe c:\users\admin\Desktop\ScreenPopMessage.vbs
```

and here is the vbs code

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

MemID = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%AvayaContent1%" )

WScript.Echo MemID
```

any idea is welcomed :)

Comment: Do you have to use a batch script?  this can all be done with a VB script.

Comment: yes, since i have to call the batch file using Avaya ip agent application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
Thank you Sorceri for helping

in order to use the data passed from Avaya IP agent application in addition to the text file data, i have modified the codes as following

the BAT file

```
SET AvayaContent1=%1
START c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe c:\users\admin\Desktop\ScreenPopMessage.vbs
```

and the vbs script file

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

UserID = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%AvayaContent1%" )

Dim InputFile 
Dim FSO, oFile 
Dim strData 
InputFile = "c:\users\admin\Desktop\output.txt" 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile) 
strData = oFile.ReadAll 
oFile.Close

set FSO = nothing
set oFile = nothing

intButton = WshShell.Popup ("User ID: " + UserID + "  Agent ID: " + strData, 0, " Avaya Caller Screen Pop ", 0 + 64)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can all go into one vbs script.

'bat file

```
call "c:\users\admin\Desktop\ScreenPopMessage.vbs"
```

'vbs file

```
Option Explicit 
Dim InputFile 
Dim FSO, oFile 
Dim strData 
InputFile = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\output.txt" 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile) 
strData = oFile.ReadAll 
oFile.Close


WScript.Echo strData


set FSO = nothing
set oFile = nothing
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this to be one of the more important reasons to use `VBS` instead of `BAT`.

Comment: thanks a lot.
very helpful, but still i have to use the batch file.
the application which i am using unable to call .vbs ,,, .bat only

Comment: All you need in your BAT file is a call to the vbs script.  See edit

Comment: AHA,  good
we are become closer to the answer.
Actually, i want to pass data from my application (phone number) to the BAT file, then pass this data in addition to the context of the text file to the vbs script.
now i can do them separately, but i need them in one vbs script